# Passing a long string between Java and PHP?

Tags: java, php, http

I have a method which takes a very long string, 90,860 characters and passes this to a PHP page which is then inserted into a database. I've read that there isn't a limit on the size of a PHP post upto about 8mb. I'm assuming that this length of string should be ok.

```
    msg = URLEncoder.encode(stringToEncode.toString(),"UTF-8"); 

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.com/insert.php?data="+msg);
        HttpResponse response1 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

I know that this works as I can insert short plain strings.

On my PHP page I just get the post data like:

```
    $data = $_GET['data'];
```

And insert it. Do I need to add some extra php to de-code the post message? I read that it should be done automatically by PHP.

The problem is that with the long string I either get a 500 error or if I take the string and put it in my browser I just get a page not available.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using a POST request to send data in the URL?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Post.

Comment: Well... My advice is that you send data in the request body, not the URL.

Comment: @EricBanderhide no, you're not.

Comment: Youre using "httpPost" but u send the data in GET way, check the HttpPost documentation about how to set data vars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Java program you should not pass your data, especially when it is long, in the URL, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604001/how-to-send-simple-http-post-request-with-post-parameters-in-java) for example code how to properly pass `Post` parameters

From PHP side, you should use `$data = $_POST['data'];`

Answer (score 1):

The limiting factor will be the maximum allowed length of an URL that the server is willing to accept.  I can't remember if there's some minimum all servers must support, but tests we did a while ago showed that depending on server type the URL length limit was commonly between 2k and 10k characters - this seems to be confirmed by [Paul Dixon's extensive answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url).

To circumvent this limitation, use [multipart post](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/methods/multipartpost.html)