# How to add commons-httpclient dependancy in play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0, ivy

I want to create a Post request in Play framework
found this thread 
[How to send simple http post request with post parameters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604001/how-to-send-simple-http-post-request-with-post-parameters-in-java)

The problem is I am not able to add commons-httpclient

```
"commons-httpclient" %% "commons-httpclient" % "3.1"
```

but play is throwing following error while compilation:

```
warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient_2.10/3.1/commons-   httpclient_2.10-3.1.pom
[warn] ==== Typesafe Releases Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient_2.10/3.1/commons-httpclient_2.10-3.1.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: commons-httpclient#commons-httpclient_2.10;3.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-httpclient#commons-httpclient_2.10;3.1: not     found
at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1144)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1142)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1165)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1163)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1167)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1162)
at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1170)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1135)
at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1113)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: commons-httpclient#commons-  httpclient_2.10;3.1: not found

**Not sure how 2.10 is added to commons-httpclient and made it commons-  httpclient_2.10**

Any idea how to resolve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"commons-httpclient" % "commons-httpclient" % "3.1",
```

is right configuration

Comment: Yes this is correct.  The double percent between the group id and artifact id appends the Scala binary version onto the artifact id.  So `"commons-httpclient" %% "commons-httpclient" % "3.1"` translates to `"commons-httpclient" % "commons-httpclient_2.10" % "3.1"`.  However as the other answer points out, Play's HTTP client should usually be used instead of the HTTP commons one.

Answer (score 4):

Playframework provides everything you need to make any HTTP call.

To make a POST request :

```
Promise<WS.Response> result = WS.url("http://localhost:9001").post("content");
```

You will find more details on Play documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaWS